# Adding attributes to EntityTypes or Properties in OData metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have a simple WebAPI2 service that uses OData (Microsoft.AspNet.OData v5.9.1, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi v5.2.3). I get the below metadata document from api/$metadata link.

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
   <edmx:DataServices>
      <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Global.Model">
         <EntityType Name="Account">
            <Key>
               <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ExtId" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="CustomerId" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="DivisionId" Type="Edm.String" />
            <Property Name="Default" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
            <NavigationProperty Name="Customer" Type="Global.Model.Customer">
               <ReferentialConstraint Property="CustomerId" ReferencedProperty="Id" />
            </NavigationProperty>
         </EntityType>
      </Schema>
   </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

I want to modify this document to return some custom attributes to client. I couldn't find a proper sample or tutorial regarding this question.

My questions are;

1) Is it even possible to modify metadata like below;

```
     <EntityType Name="Account" CustomAttribute="CustomValue">
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="3" DisplayName="No" />
```

2) If I create my entities using Entity Framework Database First approach, can I use columns Length, Precision and Scale values to assign attributes?

What I found so far;

1) A closed OData [issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/9). This question seems to be related to mine, but I can't find SetNamespacePrefixMappings() function or similar anywhere. This function is from Microsoft.Data.Edm but my project has Microsoft.OData.Edm v6.15.0 reference

2) A post about vocabularies on odata.org and a [sample](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataCapabilitiesVocabularySample). This may be the answer but I don't know how can I use them. With this sample one can add annotations to metadata but this is limited. Not exactly meet my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

About question 1, seems it's hard to modify this, you can only new it like:

```
new EdmBinaryTypeReference(
       (IEdmPrimitiveType)primitiveTypeReference.Definition,
       primitiveTypeReference.IsNullable,
       false,
       maxLength);
```

About question 2, this doc can help you to use the feature: http://odata.github.io/odata.net/#02-07-define-annotations